# jQuery .html() does not work as expected

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have these lines:

```
var text = "SL2.50ch00 11231303 11233176 Solyc00g015740 . +<br/>SL2.50ch00 11234321 11236093 Solyc00g015750 . +";
$("#regions").html(text);
```

and the following textarea:

```
<textarea required="required" class="form-control" rows="6" id="regions" name="regions"></textarea>
```

I am trying to add text inside, with breaklines `<br/>`. But the `<br/>` tags are displayed. `HTML` is not applied. So, I literally see this text:

`SL2.50ch00 11231303 11233176 Solyc00g015740 . +<br/>SL2.50ch00 11234321 11236093 Solyc00g015750 . +"`

Answer (score 2):

Using `html()` function to set the value for a `<textarea>` wont work the way a normal html element would. Use `val()` function and `\n` instead of `<br>`

```js
var text = "SL2.50ch00 11231303 11233176 Solyc00g015740 . +\n SL2.50ch00 11234321 11236093 Solyc00g015750 . +";
$("#regions").val(text);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea required="required" class="form-control" rows="6" id="regions" name="regions"></textarea>
```

Answer (score 2):

As an alternative to @Rejith answer, you can use Line Feed(`&#10;`)  and Carriage Return(`&#13;`)

```js
var text = "SL2.50ch00 11231303 11233176 Solyc00g015740&#13;&#10;SL2.50ch00 11234321 11236093 Solyc00g015750";
$("#regions").html(text);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea required="required" class="form-control" rows="6" cols="80" id="regions" name="regions"></textarea>
```

Answer (score 0):

Rejith is correct also you can use `append` as well.

```
var text = "SL2.50ch00 11231303 11233176 Solyc00g015740 .\n SL2.50ch00 11234321 11236093 Solyc00g015750 . +";
$("#regions").append(text);
```